# Entering Ukraine with someone else's car

Tags: automobiles, ukraine

I am planning to travel to Ukraine for a couple of weeks this summer by car, but the car is not registered in my name. I know from experience that other countries often have special regulations for such cases to prevent transport of stolen cars. I do of course have the car registration papers and a green insurance card valid for Ukraine, but do I need any further supporting documents, since it is not my own car?

I have already found a lot of conflicting information on the net or in different fora, so I would really appreciate if any answer would also link to official resources, be it in Ukrainian or English. I have already tried to contact Ukrainian authorities, but I don't get any answers.

- I have not found any information on the [Ukrainian Customs' (State Fiscal Service)](http://sfs.gov.ua/en/) web pages.
- I have not found any information on the [Ukrainian State Border Guard's](https://dpsu.gov.ua/en/) web pages.
- I have not found any information on the [Ukrainian embassy in Germany's](https://germany.mfa.gov.ua/de/index/city/id/18) (where I live) web pages.

My situation is mentioned in the [travel advice for Ukraine](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/aussenpolitik/laender/ukraine-node/ukrainesicherheit/201946) from the German Federal Foreign Office. They claim that I need a notarized and apostilled power of attorney from the car's owner, which has to be translated into Ukrainian by an approved interpreter. I am however not sure if this information is up to date and this information is in any case not authorative. The subject has been discussed in different internet fora, where it is both claimed that an informal power of attorney is sufficient (no need for a notarization, apostille or proper translation) or that a power of attorney used to be required, but the requirement has been lifted completely.

Answer (score 3):

One traveling abroad with a vehicle not registered in his/her name needs a user permit "Benützungsbewilligung/Vollmacht in german".  You you get it from the German Automobile Club like **avd** which is sufficient to travel abroad with someone's vehicle.

But for Ukriane it should be  **notarially attested** (see the source - Vollmacht, Federal Foreign Office of Germany, Ministry of Foreign Affairs Austria and  Honorary Consul Ukarine).

For fruther information you should call **avd**, **adac** or other Automobilclubs  in Germany.

Source: [ÖAMTC in Austria](https://www.oeamtc.at/thema/vorschriften-strafen/vollmacht-fuer-geborgtes-auto-benuetzungsbewilligung-fuer-fahrten-mit-fremden-kfz-ins-ausland-16636097)

Source: [AVD in Germany](https://www.avd.de/wissen/recht/formulare-dokumente/)

Source: [Vollmacht for Ukraine - notarized](https://www.oeamtc.at/laenderinfo/vergleich/sections?countries=16323297&categories=16309468)

Source: [Federal Foreign Office Germany - "Einreise mit Kfz"](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/aussenpolitik/laender/ukraine-node/ukrainesicherheit/201946)

Source: [Ministry of Foreign Affairs Austria -  "Verkehr & Klima"](https://www.bmeia.gv.at/reise-aufenthalt/reiseinformation/land/ukraine/)

Source: [Honorary Consul Ukarine-  "Ratgeber für Reisende"](http://www.hk-ukr.at/index.php/de/ratgeber-fuer-reisenede)

**Edit**: One can`t say that information posted on differnt forums (without sources) is valid and the information posted on Federal Foreign Office of  Germany or Austria which even recommend different Autommobileclubs for further information on Ukraine is invalid.

Comment: You are here just linking to different, contradicting and non-authorative sources. German and Austrian automobile clubs do not decide which documents are required to enter Ukraine by car and the information you are linking to is also in conflict with the information from the German Federal Foreign Office.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo Yes, they are not fully authorative organisations like Verkehrsamt but these clubs even issue international driving license, provide traffic information and even do §57a assessment (in austria). These clubs  work together on international basis. The Information provided by these clubs is correct. Where as the  Federal Foreign Office  is responsible for  country's foreign policy and not the documents you need for a car that you want to take to other country.

Comment: Since the information from ADAC, AVD and ÖAMTC contradict eachother, they can obviously not all be correct. ÖAMTC also claim that you need a power of attorney to use someone else's car in Germany and Norway and this is definitively incorrect. There is no such legal requirement in any of these two countries.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo Yes, ÖAMTC is from austria  and ADAC etc. is from Germany. So according to ÖAMTC you need Benützungsbewilligung "user permit " when you go to Germany and vica versa.  But all this is in the EU and it is not strict. Even sometimes rental companies don't even ask for international driving license but it is recommended to have one (certainly in case of accident). You can take your car without permit and may be they let you in but don`t let you out or no one cares.

Comment: I am just saying that the requirements for vehicle papers listed by ÖAMTC to enter Germany and Norway are incorrect, so why should I believe that they are listing the correct requirements for Ukraine? These requirements have AFAIK nothing to do with the EU. I know for example that going to Poland with someone else's car also requires a power of attorney, even if I come from another EU country.

Comment: What is incorrect? Just call the ADAC or any other club and confirm it locally.

Comment: What is incorrect? I already explained that in a previous comment: 'ÖAMTC also claim that you ...'.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo As said ÖAMTC is from austria. So they are telling if one austrian goes to germany with someone`s car then he/she needs it (only power of attorney ). Tell me what is incorrect? I was in poland, switzerland, germany etc..  with  someone's car without even power of attorney and no one even asked me about it (not even when I enterd to Bayern at temporary checkpoint). But correct procedure is to have one! Because Ukraine is not in the EU/Schengen so you need notarially attested power of attorney according to them to be 100% correct.

Comment: Look, I am just repeating myself here and have already explained the issue. If you go from Austria to Germany or Norway with a borrowed car, you *do not* need a power of attorney from the vehicle's owner. There is nothing in German or Norwegian law or regulations requiring so. Please read and understand what I am objecting to.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo - Source? You are saying somthing that you know but you have no source?

Comment: As I also already wrote, the source is the laws and regulations in Germany and Norway. In Germany, the use of foreign vehicles is regulated in 'Verordnung über die Zulassung von Fahrzeugen zum Straßenverkehr' §§ 20-22. In Norway, the relevant regulation is 'Forskrift om bruk av utenlandsk motorvogn i riket og om særskilt registrering av motorvogn for midlertidig bruk'.

Comment: Lets see the german law - § 20-22. There is nothing it says that you can take someone's car to germany without his permission (user permit) and no word about if the car is from other country (in the context) . Even the  § 20 abs. 4 mention Automobilclubs to get proper documents (which you said are non-authorative in your first comment). I don`t think I have to check Norway law. So you have the information - use it or not - it is up to you.

Comment: I give up. There is of course no law pointing out everything you don't have to consider. Just as you won't find a specific law allowing you to chew chewing gum or wearing a blue t-shirt when driving a car in Germany, you will not find a law listing all the documents you don't need to drive a foreign car. The law lists *all the required* documents and since it does not mention that you need a power of attorney from the owner if the vehicle is not registered in your name, you don't need one.

Comment: §20.4 simply says that the potentially required translation of the car's registration certificate can be done by a foreign automobile club. It does not say that ÖAMTC is an authorative source for Ukrainian legal requirements.

Comment: I am sorry, but your answer does not contribute with anything beyond the  'conflicting information on the net' I already mentioned and emphasized in the question. That is why I explicitely asked for authorative resources and that would probably be Ukrainian authorities, or at least not contradicting information from different foreign automobile clubs.

Comment: You can believe anything you want and even deny that automobileclubs are just giving false information. The thing is that you cant drive a car in germany or else where when documents are not conform to that country. Even both paragraphs 20-22 mention automobileclubs for proper documentation and even translation (i.e. they can be helpful). So got it?

Comment: read this "Einreise mit Kfz" - https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/aussenpolitik/laender/ukraine-node/ukrainesicherheit/201946

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93035/discussion-between-n-randhawa-and-tor-einar-jarnbjo).